# How to make macros work while in Slide Show mode?

Tags: vba, mouseevent, powerpoint, mouseover

I have a set of grouped images in the PowerPoint slide.

When in Slide Show Mode (full screen) and I hover over these grouped images the slide event needs to take place. Usually when the mouse's slider is slide it ends full screen mode or moves to next slide. Instead I want the mouse slide event to take place. How can I do this in VBA or is there setting in PowerPoint to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're after, but perhaps this will help:

You can assign any shape (including shapes that are groups of other shapes) an Action Setting (it's on the Insert tab).  The Action Setting can be triggered by either a mouse click or ... and this is what you want, I think ... a mouse OVER.

The action can do a variety of things, including trigger a macro (ie, a VBA subroutine in the same presentation file).  The macro can receive a reference to the shape that triggered it as well.  For example, if you assign this as the macro to run, when you hover over the shape, you'll get a message box with the shape's name:

```
Sub WhoAmI(oSh as Shape)
   MsgBox oSh.Name
End Sub
```

MouseOver is actually not triggered by the mouse cursor being over the shape so much as by moving from NOT over the shape to being over the shape.  Most of the time this distinction isn't important, but if you do a mouseover over a full-slide shape, it won't work.